# CPU fan error after replacing the fan

Tags: cpu, fan

I am getting a "CPU fan error" after replacing the fan. The fan makes noises at that time as well.

I rebooted it and it worked. Next time the error occurred I rebooted again, but that didn't solve the issue this time.

How can I determine what is causing this? The fan runs when the error occurs.

Should I keep tinkering? Can it damage?

Comment: When you say the fan "makes noise" do you mean a normal running noise or something else? What is the make and model of the fan? Does it mount directly on the processor heatsink?

Comment: First thing I'd do is make sure the fan is spinning.  And, with the power off, make sure that it turns freely when you flick it with your finger.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 kinds of fans

1. 2 wire, both wires used to power the fan, fixed rpm
2. 3 wire, 3rd wire is the rpm signal circuit for the motherboard to monitor rpm, fixed rpm.
3. 4 wire, these are special Pulse Width Modulated (PWM) fans, they have internal temp and rpm sensors, these are controlled by the motherboard, the motherboard can change fan speeds on the fly as needed.

You need to use the same type as was removed from the PC.

Answer (score 2):

Two things came to mind:

(a) turn jumper array around (if it's not "polarized") and plug it back in

(b) move it over one pin and try again.

No promises either one will nail the problem; just some successes with the above techniques over the years.

Comment: the jumper cannot be turned around or moved it over one pin as there is no space.

Answer (score 1):

There are also fans without sensors. They report nothing back.

Comment: how do i check that..?

Answer (score 1):

Check you BIOS settings for the acceptable fan speed range, the lower limit may be too high if your new fan is more efficient than the old one.

Check the mounting of the new fan and ensure it's central on the heatsink and not skewed to one side.

If it has screws holding it in place on the heatsink, make sure you haven't overtightened one corner.

Check that you don't have a nearby cable interfering with the fan.

If you inadvertently stop the fan for any length of time it is possible you could damage your processor.

Answer (score 0):

Check the motherboard manual. Fans seem to come in 3-pin and 4-pin versions, and some motherboards need you to tell them what kind by placing a jumper. Especially if the motherboard connector is a 4-pin type that can accept either.

Comment: Its a 4 pin fan.